# With GAWK 5, is it possible to get the current line number (of the code, not the input !), current function and source code file name?

Tags: awk

In some languages like Python, it is possible to log data with several "metadata" such as:

- filename
- function name
- line number
- etc.

For example, in Python:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level="INFO",
                    format=("%(asctime)s - %(process)d - %(levelname)s"
                            " - [%(funcName)s():%(filename)s:%(lineno)s]"
                            " - %(message)s"))
logging.info("toto")
```

This would send to STDOUT:

```
2023-04-14 15:03:26,375 - 21680 - INFO - [<module>():test.awk:38] - toto
```

I wish to achieve the same with GAWK 5.0.1, but I am not able to find any [built-in](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Auto_002dset.html) variables that convey this kind of information.

Can this be achieve in Gawk ? If yes, how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no builtin variables for this but you can get the source file name and line number by forcing a warning to be printed where you want your message to appear, e.g.:

```
$ cat tst.awk
function foo() {
    if ( 1 != 2 ) {
        printf "The sky is falling " > "/dev/stderr"; log(-1)
    }
}

BEGIN {
    foo()
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk
The sky is falling awk: tst.awk:3: warning: log: received negative argument -1
```

I used `log(negative number)` but pick whatever construct you like that'd cause gawk to print a run-time warning.

Obviously you'd have to post-process that to get it into the format you'd like but at least in `tst.awk:3` it'd have the source file name and line number you want. You'd have to manually add the function name as a string to the `printf`.

IMHO you'd be better off just writing a logging function with meaningful identifiers for each occurrence of an error, warning, notice, or trace message.

Comment: While not ideal, that seems to be the least complicated for the most benefits.

Comment: Very clever trick, especially that such things are needed mostly during initial development or ad-hoc debugging

Answer (score 1):

to elaborate upon `@Ed Morton`'s point, `PROCINFO` might give you full visibility of the code itself (under certain invocation styles, excluding `-c` `--traditional` or `-P` `--posix` flags), and unlike the profiler or pretty printing features, this approach retains all the original formatting styling

```
date | gawk -tbe '{

  PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc"

    __ = "argv"
   OFS = "\14"
  OFMT = "%.39f"

  for (_ in PROCINFO[__]) {

    print " PROCINFO[\42"(__)"\42]["sprintf(" %2s ",                         
                     _) "] ::\14\14\10 \47" \ 
            PROCINFO[__][_]            "\47"     
  }  
}'
```

---

```
 PROCINFO["argv"][  0 ] ::

                        'gawk'
 PROCINFO["argv"][  1 ] ::

                        '-tbe'
 PROCINFO["argv"][  2 ] ::

                        '{

  PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc"

    __ = "argv"
   OFS = "\14"
  OFMT = "%.39f"

  for (_ in PROCINFO[__]) {
 
    print " PROCINFO[\42"(__)"\42]["sprintf(" %2s ",
                     _) "] ::\14\14\10 \47" \
            PROCINFO[__][_]            "\47"
  }  
}'
```

so one very indirect and inefficient approach would be using the same data values (if possible), and have the function essentially re-create the same execution order with a difference instance of `gawk`, capture that error message and line number, then pair that info with the original codes from `PROCINFO` - perhaps that might work ?

But overly detailed error messages sometimes could also be a curse, like  the `java` ones :

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Class java.lang.Object.getClass()' on a null object reference
       at androidx.lifecycle.Lifecycling.lifecycleEventObserver(Lifecycling.java:82)
       at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry$ObserverWithState.<init>(LifecycleRegistry.java:354)
       at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.addObserver(LifecycleRegistry.java:170)
       at expo.modules.notifications.notifications.service.NotificationsHelper.<init>(NotificationsHelper.java:96)
       at expo.modules.notifications.FirebaseListenerService.createNotificationsHelper(FirebaseListenerService.java:90)
       at expo.modules.notifications.FirebaseListenerService.onMessageReceived(FirebaseListenerService.java:86)
       at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.dispatchMessage(com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@@20.2.4:85)
       at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.passMessageIntentToSdk(com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@@20.2.4:55)
       at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.handleMessageIntent(com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@@20.2.4:34)
       at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.handleIntent(com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@@20.2.4:23)
       at com.google.firebase.messaging.EnhancedIntentService.lambda$processIntent$0$EnhancedIntentService(com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@@20.2.4:43)
       at com.google.firebase.messaging.EnhancedIntentService$$Lambda$0.run(:6)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.util.concurrent.zza.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@17.2.1:6)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. But I think I'll just do something simple and go for Ed's "hack".