# In a awk script, is it a way to get the number of line being executed?

Tags: awk

In bash, are several variables `LINENO`, `FUNCNAME`... very useful for debugging.

Writing a *gawk* scrip, i have put a little *debug* function in order to follow variable values. This function is call in other function or rules.

```
# @function debug
# @description
# Write a line in the log file
# @arg text string the text being logged
# @arg ln integer the number of the line being executed
function debug(text, ln) {
  printf("%4s %4s %s\n", ln, NR, text) > log_file
}
```

Is it a way, in the caller function|rule, to get the current line number and pass it to the debug function ?

I have found nothing in https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/index.html

### adds

I'm trying the debug function, being a little confused with the antislashs, parenthesis... :

```
function debug(text, id) {
  system("awk /debug\\(.*," id "\\) {print NR " text "} "  path_to_me " > log_file)
}
```

and calling the debug with an unique id : `debug("my var: " var, my_id)`
The debug function should introspect the script to find the debug call with the unic id.
Is it possible to solve the problem this way ?

Thanks

Comment: No. See [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76019811/1745001) to the question I closed this as a dup of for the best you can do. So you'd remove the `ln` argument from `debug()` and then wherever you call it do `debug('whatever"); log(-1)` or similar. You might also want to change `printf ... > log_file` to `printf .... > "/dev/stderr"` and then redirect stderr outside of the script so the debug and warning messages go to the same place.

Comment: Yes. I guess it is a way to do it in a tricky way... If there is a `path_to_me="/path/to/current/script"` in the `BEGIN`. If there is something like `system("awk /debug\\(.*," id "\\) {print NR " text "} "  path_to_me "> " "path/to/log") in the `function debug (text, id)` and a call like `debug("my text", "my_id")`, then, with the id, the script should introspect itself to find matches and then the line number where the debug was call. But i'm a little confused with the antislachs, parenthesis... I still get errors. I re-open if somebody find the right way to write a clean debug function.

Comment: You've changed the question. You originally asked "Is it a way, in the caller function|rule, to get the current line number and pass it to the debug function ?" which is why I answered "No" as that is 100% the right answer to that question and closed it as a dup of the existing duplicate question. You're now asking for help with a function you wrote to try to do something specific to help you get around that fact - rollback this question to what it originally was and then ask a new question about that so we can help you with that new question.

Comment: @ed-morton Sorry. You are right according to [this wider question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76015410/with-gawk-5-is-it-possible-to-get-the-current-line-number-of-the-code-not-the/76019811#76019811) (function name, source code). Maybe I'm wrong, but in the header, my question was "in a awk script" and only "line number". So i though i could add matter in the body. I'm not a progammer and i expected that someone could say if the introspection with a uid was a way to get the line number. And it starts to be late in France, I've no more strength to open a new question. Maybe tomorrow.